# Raster calculator iteration

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, iterator

I have a set of rasters within a file gdb in which are of continuous values (NDVI). I am trying to build an attribute table for each raster in order to reclassify into either 1 or 2 (water or land). I was able to get a model working on a single raster, but the iterator fails. Within the model I am using raster calculator with expression:  INT(("raster"+0.05)*100) to get to an integer, then using reclassify to get values either 1 or 2. 
Model fails with a 000539 code "cannot concatenate str and flt". 
Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

The error is as expected, you are adding 0.05 to a string containing the text *raster*. Have a look at [this page on raster operators](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Working_with_operators_in_Map_Algebra/00p600000008000000/). Note they enclose the name of the raster in Raster().

Comment: Right, in fact I was using INT(%Name% + 0.05)*100).